Why Subtasks are marked High Backpressure when ratio is 0 in Flink
i have a project in Flink 1.11.3 where i can observe some Backpressure on one of the Pipelines:

I was expecting to see Status High only on first three SubTasks, because Ratio is above 0.5 there.
Why there is the high back pressure on all of them? Can it be some bad Kafka Source configuration or it's just Flink Dashboard bug?
